# Flutter Web: iOS Swipe Back Navigation Issue with GetX Routing

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter web project specifically on iOS where swiping from left to right to navigate back results in all routes disappearing and displaying a white screen. I've set up my routing using GetX, but even after trying the example of go_router, the problem persists.
Does anyone have experience resolving this specific problem on Flutter Web for iOS with the getx system?

This is my problem with getx:

[image: getx]

And with go_router:

[image: go_router]

Comment: you can control the swipe gesture from ios to stop this isssue